# Display scroll bar in a mobile emulator

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, scrollbar, mobile-website

The following Jquery code produces a `scroll bar` in a opera mini mobile emulator browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) & Chrome Frame
        Remove this if you use the .htaccess -->
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

        <title>buttons_create_avoid</title>
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="author" content="siddarth" />

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Jquery library/themes2/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./Jquery library/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./Jquery library/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div data-role = "page" data-theme = "b">

            <div data-role = "header">
                <h1>This is Buttons Page</h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role = "content">
                <button>Button</button>
                <input type="submit" value="submit" data-corners = "false" /> <!-- If data-corners is false then square button -->
                <input type="reset" value="reset" data-icon = "home"/> <!-- A pic is inserted in the button -->
                <input type = "submit" value = "This button fits to the length of the word" data-inline />
                <input type="submit" value = "submit" data-shadow = "false" /> <!-- Now this button has no shadow like other -->
                <p>Now The standard Jquery buttons will not be created, cos of: data-role = "none"</p>

                <input type = "submit" value="submit" data-role = "none" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Most of the jQuery mobile pages produces that annoying vertical navigation or the scroll bar, when I open this page in the mobile emulator.

What is the reason for this.?

![The emulator](/home/siddarth/Pictures/Screenshot from 2013-03-12 20:18:42.png)

Comment: Change to latest jQuery Mobile. Some version of Mobile Opera have problems with a viewport meta tag, so use latest browser version. Play with other viewport tags, for example: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/> , take a look at this link: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/UqaES/embedded/result/ , if everything is displayed correctly then your problem is in a possibilities I mentioned at the beginning of this comment.